# Maven dependencies not included in project deployed on Websphere Liberty

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, maven-3

I am using Eclipse Luna, Maven 3 and Websphere Liberty 8.5.5. I have added websphere liberty server in eclipse. The EAR/WAR project deployed in liberty does not include maven dependencies in WEB-INF/lib of WAR. If I export EAR or WAR the exported file has all the dependencies included. What could be going wrong?

Comment: What's the problem? Is anything not working? Did you check the WEB-INF/lib folder in the target directory? Maven dependencies are by default put to WEB-INF/lib during deployment, but they are not in the src folder. You can check that in the Project properties > Deployment Assembly.

Comment: The deployment assembly was missing Maven dependencies. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While working with Maven projects in Eclipse, make sure your Maven dependencies are correctly configured in `Project properties > Deployment Assembly` to be deployed to `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Gas has the right answer. Just here a screenshot:

[image: Eclipse Properties for Project]

If the Maven dependencies are missingf  click   then "Java Build Path Entiries" and the select "Maven Dependencies"

In my workspace this setting will be lost when I do Maven/Update Project.